# How to listen to ERC721 transactions using ethers.js?

Tags: etherscan, ethers.js

How can I listen to NFT minting transactions (ERC721) using ethers.js ?

Answer (score 0):

```
// 创建一个合约实例
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);

// 监听 Transfer 事件
contract.on("Transfer", (from, to, tokenId) => {
  // 获取代币的元数据 URI
  const tokenURI = await contract.tokenURI(tokenId);
  // 解析元数据 JSON
  const metadata = await fetch(tokenURI).then(res => res.json());
  // 获取代币的名称
  const name = metadata.name;
});
```

from: new Bing